# Re-Classifying data

Tags: r, matrix, classification, raster, pheatmap

I have made  matrix using pheatmap and need to be able to reclassify it into 8 classifications. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I have placed the code below.

```
   pheatmap(y, cluster_row=FALSE, cluster_col=FALSE, display_numbers=TRUE, 
      color=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n=10,name="RdYlBu")))(8))
```

The packages I have used are as follows: RColorBrewer,rgdal,ggplot2,pheatmap and raster. I am new to programming so please don't be too harsh.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: alway better to include a small example of your data, preferably using dput so that it can be easily reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is an argument: `kmeans_k`. Did you try setting that to 8?